# Cant get Xampp to follow symlinks

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp

Im running Xampp on a windows 7 machine. I want to follow symlinks, but cant get it to work.

Anyone offer any help.

httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot E:\xampp\htdocs\xampp
ServerName localhost
<Directory E:\xampp\htdocs\xampp>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" combined
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot E:\PHPDev
ServerName mypc.localhost
<Directory E:\PHPDev>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog "logs/mypc.localhost-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/mypc.localhost-access.log" combined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer out.

Kind of feel stupid, it was because I was pasting a shortcut and assumed that it was the same. I needed to use the windows "mklink" command.

Didnt know they were different.

Comment: This is great and solved the issue, thanks! Just wanted to add the `mklink` syntax (I forgot the `/D` option and got an odd "forbidden" error):
`mklink /D yourwebsite C:\path\to\your\website`.

Comment: I find it odd that the *only way* to create a working shortcut seems to be using the `mklink` command. I tried several other methods -- XAMPP only respected this one. Thx to both PapaLazarou and Matt07!

Answer (score 0):

Create an `.htaccess` in your Document Root

Copy and Paste,

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
```

I have a feeling that your configuration in the Virtualhost is been overwritten by a other configuration file. Try to create the `.htaccess` file